# Python : Sort file by arbitrary column, where column contains time values

Tags: python, sorting

I have a .txt file for a person, and next to each person they have two times. This is the .txt file

```
 Xantippe 09:00 11:00
 Erica 10:00 12:06
 Marcia 09:30 11:45
 Elizabeth 10:15 12:10
 Angela 11:30 13:45
 Freda 12:00 14:20
 Maria 12:30 14:10
```

I am required to read the file, then get each line, read it, and sort the whole list by the second time. Remember in the file the numbers are string objects. So basically the time that is the earliest i.e. 11:00 Should be at the top of the list along with their previous time and name. eg. `Xantippe 09:00 11:00` and then on another line the next one etc.

So far I have done:

```
from Practise1 import timeCalc
with open('LadiesRace.txt', 'r') as f:
  readf = f.read();
  timeX = timeCalc()
  lis = readf.split('\n')
  with open('sortByFinishTime.txt','w') as w:
    def compare(x,y):
      if x[1] > y[1]:
        return 1
      if x[1] < y[1]:
        return -1
      return 0
    #lis.sort()
    for l in lis:
      #line = l.strip()
      slist = l.split(' ')
      print slist[2]
```

The problem is that I cannot use a dictionary, only a list. I have managed to sort the list by name in ascending order, but how do I sort with the last time?

Comment: Is this actually *your* code?  If you have written this, surely you should already know the answer.

Comment: This is actually my code. I was working with dictionaries before, and with lists now, but im finding it difficult to get this solution

Comment: You've already managed to sort for column index 1 pretty nicely - why not change that to 2?  Or am I completely misunderstanding the question?

Comment: lol im a 23 year old man, im just new to all this thats all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, you need to get your data into a usable format... So let's load it into a list in memory - it's important to note that `dict`s do not inherently have order, so we want to use a list.

```
with open('myfile.txt') as fin:
    lines = [line.split() for line in fin]
```

This will remove any trailing newlines and break it up by the space character... so we end up with:

```
[['Xantippe', '09:00', '11:00'], ['Erica', '10:00', '12:06'], ['Marcia', '09:30', '11:45'], ['Elizabeth', '10:15', '12:10'], ['Angela', '11:30', '13:45'], ['Freda', '12:00', '14:20'], ['Maria', '12:30', '14:10']]
```

Then, we can use the `.sort` method of a `list` - `itemgetter` is a handy method for getting the nth element of a sequence, so we have name, start, end, where end is the 2nd index (based on zero being the first, which will be the name)

```
from operator import itemgetter
lines.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
```

And we end up with:

```
[['Xantippe', '09:00', '11:00'], ['Marcia', '09:30', '11:45'], ['Erica', '10:00', '12:06'], ['Elizabeth', '10:15', '12:10'], ['Angela', '11:30', '13:45'], ['Maria', '12:30', '14:10'], ['Freda', '12:00', '14:20']]
```

Then write it back out:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for el in lines:
        fout.write('{0}\n'.format(' '.join(el)))
```

Comment: How do I write these as lines on a txt file?

Comment: @MuhammedBhikha as you were doing - updated with a quick example OTTOMH

Comment: @Alfe Off The Top Of My Head

Comment: `with open('output.txt', 'w') as f: print >>f, '\n'.join(' '.join(line) for line in lines)`   (But Jon's works as well of course.)

Comment: @Alfe `print >> fout, ' '.join(el)` would work, and so would yours, but there's no need to pre-build the entire output file as string before writing it

Comment: And no disadvantage as well, as long as the output is small.  I just like the functional way of handlig things; typically less error-prone due to the logical restrictions.  But that may be personal choice.

Comment: one last question, say for example I wanted to add another index to the list so `[Name time1 time2 newindex]` for each item, how do I do that?

Comment: @MuhammedBhikha If it's already in your input file, it'll automatically be in your list as another element - if you want to look at adding elements - then look at `list.append`

Comment: @alfe yup, the "functional" way, assuming `map` is lazy (3.x) or using `imap`, is `fmt = '{}\n'.format; fout.writelines(map(fmt, lines))` or to ensure it across version `fout.writelines(fmt(line) for line in lines))`